# Using 'cat' and avoiding encoding change

Tags: encoding, concatenation

Be gentle; it's my first time here and I've only really learnt PS on the job over the past 9 months, so my knowledge is limited.
You may have to talk slowly and loudly, as if you were a Daily Mail reader trying to order cheese on toast in France without getting Brie.

So, I am using the cat command to concatenate several files, and everything works excellently, except my resulting file is, as you'd expect, UCS2 Little Endian encoded.

I need UTF8, but the fact that I'm using cat instead of Get-Content seems to cause a problem.
And if I use Get-Content and Set-Content or Get-Content and Out-File my script doesn't like the fact that my intended output file doesn't already exist.
So, bearing in mind that I need to save my original files off to an archive location, I need to concatenate my existing files, I need to then get rid of my originals (not in the archive) then move my resulting files to another location, this works but my output is in UCS2 Little Endian:

```
$RenFld = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals"
$RenArchive = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Archive"
$RenDone = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Done"

Copy-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -destination $RenArchive -force

cat -path $RenFld\ren_*pak_emlcon1.dat > $RenFld\pak_emlcon1.dat

Remove-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -force

get-childItem -path $RenFld\*.dat | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item

Copy-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -destination $RenDone -force

Remove-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -force
```

This:

```
$RenFld = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals"
$RenArchive = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Archive"
$RenDone = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Done"

Copy-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -destination $RenArchive -force

Get-Content -path $RenFld\ren_*pak_emlcon1.dat -Encoding UTF8 > Set-Content $RenFld\pak_emlcon1.dat

Remove-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -force

get-childItem -path $RenFld\*.dat | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item

Copy-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -destination $RenDone -force

Remove-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -force
```

and this:

```
$RenFld = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals"
$RenArchive = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Archive"
$RenDone = $env:homedir + "\export\renewal\e-renewals\Done"

Copy-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -destination $RenArchive -force

Get-Content -path $RenFld\ren_*pak_emlcon1.dat -Encoding UTF8 > Out-File $RenFld\pak_emlcon1.dat

Remove-item -path $RenFld\ren_*.dat -force

get-childItem -path $RenFld\*.dat | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item

Copy-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -destination $RenDone -force

Remove-item -path $RenFld\*.dat -force
```

...don't work.
I get the following error when running my executable that uses this PS:

```
-------- Error Details
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$homedirexport\renewal\e-renewals\pak_emlcon1.dat'.
At $cliutl\eren_conc.ps1:13 char:12
+ Get-Content <<<<  -path $RenFld\ren_*pak_emlcon1.dat -Encoding UTF8 > Out-Fil
e $RenFld\pak_emlcon1.dat
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBin 
   dingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I'm way out of my depth and would appreciate some assistance.

I promise I have searched the forum for similar subjects and questions, but my limited knowledge means I don't really know exactly what my search parameters should be, so if the answer is already out there, please swear under your breath to yourself and point me in the right direction.

Cheers for any help any of you can offer.

Ross.

Comment: I have also tried using echo $null > -path $RenFld\pak_emlcon1.dat to create my file first so that Get-Content/Set_Content works, but it doesn't. Which confuses me further. Thanks again for your patience, everyone.

Comment: I have now resolved this through a process of trial and error.
I concatenated the files in one line of code then changed the encoding in another line.
A bit scruffy, but it does the job.
Thanks to anyone who was considering this.